# Is it possible for an app to alter the Android home screen?

Tags: android

I'm a web developer. I have an idea for an Android app, but before I dive in and start learning, could someone please answer the following:

Is it possible for a regular app (installed from the Market)...

- to add/remove icons (of **other** apps) to/from the home screen?
- to rearrange icons on the home screen?
- to change the home screen's wallpaper?

To clarify: I don't want to replace the home screen application itself (I believe this is only possible on rooted phones?); I just want to programmatically customise the stock home screen. I know the user can do this themselves, but can an app do it?

If possible, please link to documentation of the relevant APIs.

Answer (score 2):

Your answer to following question

Is it possible for a regular app (installed from the Market)...

- to add/remove icons (of other apps) to/from the home screen? **No, it can only add its own icon**
- to rearrange icons on the home screen? **Again, no**
- to change the home screen's wallpaper? **Yes, you can do that**

As far as for rooted phone goes yes you can do it :)